# JQuery Onclick Change Image Src not refreshing the image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code to change the image src with jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#MyDiv').click(function() {
    $('#MyImageID').attr('src', 'image1.jpg');
});

});
</script>
```

My problem is that although it's actually changed the src it's not actually showing the new image.

Does it have to refresh the image ?

How can I sort this?

Comment: Does the image exist in the same directory as the file containing this javascript?

Comment: No...but I've tried adding the full url and it still doesn't show up although the image src IS changed.

Comment: Have you tried adding a timestamp in case there is a caching issue?

Comment: @Satch3000 is the old image still showing, or is it a broken image (or no image at all)?

Comment: It should be working see: http://jsfiddle.net/KfpzW/ I guess you have some issues with the file you are trying to assign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass some random number to the image:-

```
 $('#MyImageID').attr('src', 'image1.jpg?'+Math.random());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try detaching and re-attaching the `<img>` once you change the src

Answer (score 0):

**NOT TESTED** but should work I think

Yes you have to load image:

```
var image = document.createElement('img'); // new Image(1, 1); 
image.src = 'image1.jpg';
image.onload = function() { $('#MyImageID').attr('src', 'image1.jpg');};
```

or you can replace  tag should work too